# Compilation Error: Error: Expected identifier but got '(' msg.sender.transfer(uint(amount));

Tags: solidity, remix

I am compiling the following code on solc & remix ide:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
    contract Signed1 {
        uint val= 0;
        function withdrawOnce(int amount) public returns (uint){
           revert();
        }
        msg.sender.transfer(uint(amount));
        transferred[msg.sender] = true;

    }
```

I got the following error:

> D:\SolidityContractsSelf\Remix\From Remix Site\Integer Bugs>solc
>   sign1.sol sign1.sol:7:24: Error: Expected identifier but got '('
>       msg.sender.transfer(uint(amount));

Can some body please guide me how to get rid of this error? Is revert() still used?

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no compile errors, but not the best code and way to do that

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Signed1 {
    uint val = 0;
    mapping (address => bool) transferred;

    function withdrawOnce(int amount) public returns (uint) {
        require(amount > 0, 'only postive amount');
        require(transferred[msg.sender] == false, 'withdraw only once');
        transferred[msg.sender] = true;
        msg.sender.transfer(uint(amount));
    }

}
```

Comment: No error now but what is transferred[...] array? Is it a built-in array? If not then where is it declared? How the initial value of transferred is false?

Comment: transferred is a mapping from address to boolean, declared above and the default value is false or null im not sure, you should test it

Comment: you should also also check if the contract has balance more than the amount

Comment: @MajdTL The default value of booleans is always `false` in Solidity. Also, `null` does not exist in Solditiy

Comment: good thnx :)@JesseBusman

Comment: it is also better to let the parameter withdrawOnce(uint amount) , so you will not need to check if it is postive and you dont need to convert it with (uint amount) in transfer function, which mean less gas